# Rails and RSpec: Mock assocation collection return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have some code that uses find_or_initialize_by through an association:

```
author.posts.find_or_intialize_by(params)
```

For the purposes of some tests, I'd like to have control over what is returned. However, I can't seem to figure out what to mock.

```
author.posts.class #=> Post::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

allow(Post::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy).to receive(:find_or_initialize_by).and_return(Post.new)
```

This raises the error:

```
Post::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy does not implement: find_or_initialize_by
```

I realize I could change my query to be something like:

```
Post.find_or_initialize_by({author: author}.merge(params))
```

For the sake of claritiy, I'd like to do this through the association.

How can I mock this collection to return my record?

Comment: wait - why are you trying to return an *author* on the collection of *posts*...

Comment: @TarynEast sorry, typo while sanitizing my code for an example. I've updated it.

Comment: kewl - it made me think I'd totally misunderstood the problem :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
let(:author) { Author.new } # or whatever you'd like author to be)

it "is the name of your actual test here" do
  allow(author.posts).to receive(:find_or_initialize_by).and_return(Post.new)
end
```

Comment: :facepalm: So simple it's brilliant. And it's more precise. Thanks, @TarynEast.

Comment: hehe - I had the same reaction when I first learned about it :D